# SQL Injection PHP CTF

Tags: php, sql-injection, ctf

Is there something I can do with this information?

```
$employee_id = explode(' ', $_POST['employee_id'])[0];
$query = 'SELECT name FROM employees WHERE id = CAST('.$employee_id.' AS INT)';
```

Any SQL Injection or something like that?

I trying to do some SQL injection or reverse shell PHP to complete my hacking task

Please, someone help me?

[A pic of the test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6NTtf.png)

[Chris test result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kynh.png)

Comment: Ignore the first line for a bit, just imagine what you could put into `$employee_id` to concatenate that would do something, then work backwards

Comment: Yes, absolutely this is vulnerable to SQL injection (no, I am not going to highlight how, for obvious reasons).  You should use bound parameters instead.

Comment: I am new to this world and im trying to learn some things, i already find my 3 flags, but i break my mind with this part, how i can use the bound parameters? And i have to tell you guys that exists a page in the web server who have a form hidden where i can input the information to employee_id.

Comment: Rob meant that if this were to be used in the real world, prepared statements should be used. However, because this is CTF you are limited with what's in front of you.

Comment: hahah, i cant figure out what i have to do now lol.

Comment: I think that explode function and the CAST of sql query is the trouble. Maybe.

Comment: I just have to return the entire content of the table employee

Comment: Probably something along these lines is what you are looking for then: https://3v4l.org/qHEte

Comment: Hey Chris, the result is the same. I will edit post with the result.

Comment: That's why I said something along those lines, you'll have to play around with the specific syntax more. Maybe my CAST isn't correct, I haven't had to use that in a long time, I'm a little rusty there. But giving you the exact answer feels like it would be defeating the point of the exercise

Comment: I think you can pass new lines in and the `explode` won't see them. MySQL I think will still treat those as white space. e.g. `'1)' . PHP_EOL . 'OR' . PHP_EOL . '1=1' . PHP_EOL . '--';` swap `PHP_EOL` with new lines, `\n`.

Comment: Thats fine Chris, i already thank you for all help that you provide me.

Comment: @user3783243 the return using this stuff was nothing. Maybe i use this with what?

Comment: Did it give you a SQL error? Output the query and see what is being run, and if there are any errors. You could also try injecting tabs into it... anything except a standard space should execute inside the SQL

Comment: No :( any error, just nothing

Comment: Are you getting a fatal error, 500 status code? Do you output anything on the page? The code is the same as you have above or updated?

Comment: I getting 200 status code, normally, and nothing is outputted in the page. Im trying to use some \n to make a different code, but without effect.